# Flink 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT RestClient - Received response is abnormal

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The job of the application can be submitted to the standalone cluster， via Spring boot Application main method.

But mvn spring-boot:run will pring this exception.
In the development environment，such as， Eclipse Luna.

BUG in CentOS6.8 JDK1.8.0_161 ,The system prints the exception log as follows:

```html
09:07:20.755 tysc_log [Flink-RestClusterClient-IO-thread-4] ERROR o.a.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient - Received response was neither of the expected type ([simple type, class org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.messages.job.JobExecutionResultResponseBody]) nor an error. Response=org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient$JsonResponse@2ac43968
org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "status" (class org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.messages.ErrorResponseBody), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "errors"])
at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.messages.ErrorResponseBody["status"])
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:851)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1085)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1392)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperties(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1346)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:455)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1127)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:298)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3779)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2050)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:2547)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.parseResponse(RestClient.java:225)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$3(RestClient.java:210)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```